# unable to charge Google Nexus I9250

Tags: usb, battery, charging, samsung-nexus-s, usb-connection-mode

I am unable to charge my phone most of the times.

When I connect my phone to the USB cable which is in turn connected to the computer or charger, most of the times (about 90 percent), I am unable to see the charging sign and battery discharges. However only in some special cases, in particular when I plug in the cable in the computer just after i press the power button, that too, selectively, the phone is able to charge.

Also : After this problem, phone only connects in AC charging mode and not in USB mode.

I brought this phone from another country so service centers here refuse to accept it. I just want to charge the phone as of now.

EDIT : Today I found a new problem. After charging it to around fifty percent with an old computer, I just plugged it into the wall charger. It did show just a sign of initialization but did not continue. When I switched on the phone, the battery was reduced to 10 percent

Comment: Have you tried charging it from the wall?

Comment: wall ? you mean a wall charger ? well, I used a wall charger but it did not work :(

Comment: actually, if the cell is switched on, the wall charger does not work at all but when the ccell is switched off, it shows that the charging is starting but does not continue. However, bu plugging it in again and again, I charge to some level for emergency situations.